# Python PIL. Image does not open

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Below is my code for opening an image:

```
import Image

filename = "Golden-Gauranga.png"
image = Image.open(filename, "r")
image.show()
```

However, the image does not open. Nothing happens.

Comment: "The program does not seem to contain any errors." Besides the obvious indentation fail. Show the exact code and tell what goes wrong exactly.

Comment: Please post the code exactly as it is in the source and also explain what you mean by 'image does not open'. Is there an error? Does the program run and nothing happens? Details.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. Nothing happens after the program is run.

Comment: There can be another module named Image. Did you try `from PIL import Image`?

Comment: Yes I did. Still the image does not open.

Comment: Try putting the filename in brackets: `filename = ("Golden-Gauranga.png")`

Comment: Thanks for the input. It did not work either.

Comment: Does the program terminate or hang?

Comment: @albus_c: really... That makes no difference to anything

Comment: It terminates successfully. (exit 0)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `cv2` and `pyplot` instead of `Image`. First you need to [install OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/table_of_content_introduction/table_of_content_introduction.html) and the other modules, and then change your code to something like

```
import cv2
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
filename = "Golden-Gauranga.png"
im = cv2.imread(filename, -1)
imarray = numpy.array(im)
plt.imshow(imarray)
plt.show
```

Answer (score 0):

For now, I am opening the image file using the below code:

```
import os
os.system("gvfs-open today")
```

I am on an Ubuntu system and today is the name of the image file.